# wrap arrow styled list elements in another arrow

Tags: html, css

I have the follow `ul` that contains some `li` and are displayed/styled as arrows, and everything is working fine.

```
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
    <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
    <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that I cant seem to wrap the last 5 `li` in another "arrow".

```
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the currently working example:

```css
.phases {
  width: 960px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 18px Sans-Serif;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: #004c89;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a::after {
  border-left: 30px solid #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #004c89;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb li a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  background: #004c89;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
  border-left-color: #004c89;
}


/*
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    */

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #0078d7 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
    <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
    <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is where I'm at currently.

```css
.phases {
  /*width: 960px;*/
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 18px Sans-Serif;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: #004c89;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a::after {
  border-left: 30px solid #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #004c89;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb li a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  background: #004c89;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
  border-left-color: #004c89;
}


/*
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    */

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #0078d7 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I know it might be a simple thing, but i really struckle with it.

What i want. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider another way to create the shape using gradient and it will be easier to nest element like you want and adjust the distance and control the arrow using margin and also easily change the color with the CSS variable I used:

```css
.phases {
  width: 1500px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 18px Sans-Serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  --c: #004c89;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(var(--c), var(--c)) 20px 0 /calc(100% - 40px) 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 100% 100%/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top right, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 100% 0/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top left, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 0 100%/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 0 0/20px 51% no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  --c: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper {
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -25px;
  right: 0;
  --c:green;
  background:
  linear-gradient(var(--c), var(--c)) 20px 0 /calc(100% - 40px) 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 100% 100%/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top right, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 100% 0/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top left, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 0 100%/20px 51% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--c) 50%, transparent 50.5%) 0 0/20px 51% no-repeat;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper .breadcrumb {
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
    <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if i made my request unclear, But the last 5 li  has to be wrapped in another "arrow" so the last 5 is inside a green arrow. so a bigger green arrow surrounds the last 5 li

Comment: @PeterHansen check the update ;) .. i will change the color also

Comment: @PeterHansen check the update again, i changed the color

Comment: Thanks for the update,check the image i added to the question

Comment: @PeterHansen update again ;) ... by the way you can easily do what you want with the configuration i did

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont see the example looking like or close to the picture.

Comment: @PeterHansen what i am missing ? :) .. only the green background as i see that i can easily add, but the arrow is like what you want with simply more item

Comment: Yes the green background.

Comment: @PeterHansen i also made the green background an arrow ;)

Comment: Its awesome, I know its pushing it but can you add a white `>` at the start of the green?

Comment: @PeterHansen yes it's easy added ... you can see that i simply reused the same gradient

Comment: Its lovely, If i where to make the green "arrow" a bit longer(the nose) how is that done, what part do i scale

Comment: @PeterHansen you can play the value of the pseudo element on where i applied the gradient [left and right value)  increase/decrease them to see whant happen

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts when you styling your `li's` in a generic way and no by name class or id. So your `breadcrumb_wrapper li` is affected when this container shoud not have same styles as the others. Try use a class for every `li` You want to behave as arrow and do not use it on the container.

Starting point in the snippet

```css
.phases {
  /*width: 960px;*/
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper {
 
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 18px Sans-Serif;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow {
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: #004c89;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow.active a {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow.active a::after {
  border-left: 30px solid #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #004c89;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow:first-child a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a {
  background: #004c89;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a:after {
  border-left-color: #004c89;
}


/*
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    */

.breadcrumb .arrow a:hover {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb .arrow a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #0078d7 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="arrow" style="margin-right:50px;"><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
      <ul class="">
        <li class="arrow"><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the last 5 li being wrapped in another arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Update your css and html like this

```
.phases {
  /*width: 960px;*/
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb_wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 18px Sans-Serif;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
  background: blue;
  /* fallback color */
  background: #004c89;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li.active a::after {
  border-left: 30px solid #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #004c89;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb li a::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  background: #004c89;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
  border-left-color: #004c89;
}


/*
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
    */

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background: #0078d7;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #0078d7 !important;
}

.first-set-li{ float:left; margin-right:50px; overflow:hidden; padding-right:33px; margin-top:20px; }

.breadcrumb_wrapper ul{ padding:0px; float:left; overflow:hidden; padding-right:40px;}
.breadcrumb .breadcrumb_wrapper li a::before{ border-left: 30px solid green; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="phases">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="first-set-li"><a href="Pre-project.aspx">Pre-project</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="Analysis.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="Development.aspx">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="Implementation.aspx">Implementation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Operation.aspx">Operation</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, is it posible to make the greenbox look like an arrow with the `>` at each end

Comment: @PeterHansen . i didn't get it clearly. can you please share a screenshot for the same you requested?